# NSInternalInconsistencyException from UIPageViewController when rotating

Tags: c#, ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm on Monotouch 5.2.6 and iOS SDK 5.0.1.

I have a UIPageViewController that is a child container of another view controller.
It is created like this:

```
pageViewController = new UIPageViewController (UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.PageCurl, UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Min);
    this.AddChildViewController (pageViewController);
    pageViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController (this);
    this.viewCurrentMode.AddSubview (pageViewController.View);
```

If I rotate the device (Simulator), I get this exception in `UIApplication.SendEvent()`:

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   Reason: The number of provided view controllers (1) doesn't match the
>   number required (2) for the requested spine location
>   (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid)

The spine location is NOT "mid" but "min". Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True, you have initialized the UIPageViewController with "Min" as spine location. However, you need to implement a delegate for your page controller and override the `GetSpineLocation` method:

```
public override UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation GetSpineLocation (UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIInterfaceOrientation orientation)
{

    //return spine location according to interface orientation and whatever
    //criteria you prefer

}
```

Or, assign a method to its `GetSpineLocation` property (MonoTouch heaven! ):

```
pageViewController.GetSpineLocation = (p, o) => return <spinelocation>;
```

Still, it looks a bit unexpected behavior. I assume that the default implementation of the native `pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:` method returns "Mid" when the device rotates to landscape (although could not find info in Apple docs). Anyway, you must override the above method to get it right.

Comment: Maybe I should buy your book even though I consider myself an experienced MT developer! :-)

Comment: Hehe, books are always helpful...! ;)

Answer (score 0):

To be safe I checked the values for `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation` and they match the values of Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

Also Dimitris is right, the default **internal**, delegate (when one is not provided) returns `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Mid` when a user-provided callback is not specified (i.e. when `UIPageViewController.GetSpineLocation` is not assigned).

That's autogenerated binding code so it's a bit tricky not to return a constant for the default, nothing provided, case. However feel free to open a bug report (and link to this question) and we'll have a look at it.